# Pyglet not drawing sprites in correct positions

Tags: python, python-3.7, pyglet, ondraw

Hey I've been stuck on this issue for quite a while and was hoping someone could help me out:

I'm using pyglet and have got all of the code working in my project (even what I was having the issue with) then I restarted my computer and suddenly it didn't work...

This is the loop that is instantiating my 'Letter' objects:

```
main_st = ut.makeString("EXNXYXAXDAADUXMDXLGEQTAQXDDQSVXUTSXKHXHRXYFUXLXJUTHXYVADSUXKHUQUIXSJHXHDPKXFQUXILNXORMXRPL")
letter_list = []
for i in range(len(main_st)):
    letter_list.append(l.Letter(pyglet.resource.image("Letters/" + main_st[i] + ".png"),main_st[i],10,10))
```

And this is the Letter class constructor Letter is a subclass of pyglet.sprite.Sprite:

```
def __init__(self,im,iden,xx,yy):

        super(Letter,self).__init__(img=im,x=xx,y=yy)
```

At no point in the program do I modify the x and y coordinates of sprite but when I go to draw them, no matter what I put in for xx and yy they're always drawn in the same place on the window UNLESS I do a very large number for yy, and in those cases it simply disappears (I assume it's outside of the window).

I'm having each letter flash on the screen for 1 second and in order to do that here's my on_draw method

```
def on_draw():
    background.draw()

    if not key_manager.cur_letter == None:
        key_manager.cur_letter.draw()
```

(only key_manager.cur_letter gets drawn and that switches every second).

Comment: Solution is to do `self.x = xx` after you've done `super(Letter, self)...`. I think this depends on which Pyglet version you're using, I recon they fixed this in later versions. But this was an old issue that's been around for a bit.

Comment: I see thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be related to older versions.
But after calling `super(Letter, self)...` you could do:

```
def __init__(self,im,iden,xx,yy):
    super(Letter,self).__init__(img=im,x=xx,y=yy)
    self.x = xx
    self.y = yy
```

And that should do the trick.